# ffplay subscription to rtmp stream fails on first try

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an Electron application that does some video streaming through ffmpeg. It works fine on Windows, but I am having a small problem with it on Mac. I stream the desktop with ffmpeg, and try to subscribe to the rtmp stream. I know the rtmp stream is live because I can successfully grab a frame from it.

The problem is, when I subscribe with ffplay, it does not work, the output looks like this: 
`2018/01/01 20:57:25:618 [web]     nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0`

When I subscribe again (while the previous process is still ongoing), it works: `2018/01/01 20:57:25:828 [web]  340.93 M-V:  0.001 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=  131KB sq=    0B f=0/0`

The only difference in output to the command line is this:

```
Input #0, live_flv, from 'rtmp:{stream-url-here}':=0/0   
2018/01/01 20:57:15:427 [web]   Metadata:
2018/01/01 20:57:15:427 [web]     Server          : NGINX RTMP 
(github.com/sergey-dryabzhinsky/nginx-rtmp-module)
2018/01/01 20:57:15:427 [web]     displayWidth    : 1024
2018/01/01 20:57:15:428 [web]     displayHeight   : 640
2018/01/01 20:57:15:429 [web]     fps             : 20
2018/01/01 20:57:15:429 [web]     profile         : 
2018/01/01 20:57:15:430 [web]     level           : 
2018/01/01 20:57:15:430 [web]   Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 
316.500000, bitrate: N/A
2018/01/01 20:57:15:430 [web]     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained 
Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 1024x640, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 1k tbn, 40 
tbc
```

I am trying to figure out why it only works on the second time subscribing, and this is the difference, which I assumes signals the it successfully received the streams info, but I am trying to figure out why it only works the second time.

Thanks!!

Comment: Does it work on each additional try, so only NOT on the first try? Or is it an on/off/on/off/on/... situation?

Comment: It is an on/off situatuion